# Dependency Parse Tree Matching in python

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy, dependency-tree

I am working on **Answer Sentence Selection Problem**, and I want to **compare dependency trees** of two sentences. I am retrieving the dependency tree from spaCy and now I want to compare dependency trees. Is there any way or library in Python that I could use?

Comment: what you mean compare two sentence parser?

Comment: Actually, I want to choose a most relevant answer from a list of answer to the particular question so I want to compare question dep tree with each answer dep tree.